# I want to watch Evangelion but don't want to watch the old 90's series, is there a remake or a newer movie with the same story?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

I want to watch Evangelion but don't want to watch the old 90's series because I can't stand the animation.

Is there a remake or a newer movie with the same story ?

Comment: Honestly, if you think the animation quality of *Evangelion* is poor enough that you don't want to watch it, you're missing out on a lot of good anime.

Comment: @Eric You can't compare non CG animation to  post ~2007 CG animation really. It's a whole different level. For example, DBZ and KLK. DBZ is unwatchable compared to Kill la Kill.

Comment: That was not my point whatsoever.

Comment: @user3289 Both styles of the visuals have artistic beauty. It's the shifted aesthetic of one era to the next that sets them apart. To use a word like "unwatchable" is a bit crass and naive. For an aspect of a whole body of work that is constantly evolving, the differences makes for highly subjective discussion. It's not a bad thing that one is different from another. In the end, it's all about aesthetic. One may appreciate "older" works, while another may prefer newer trends. Don't put off one because you like the other better, they each have their own merits and demerits.

Comment: @user3289 Cars are cars and anime is anime, comparing the two is like comparing apples to oranges. They're different things that hold different value to different people. You're welcome to your own opinions. I'm merely telling you to keep an open mind, just don't go putting other people off just because they don't share the same opinion as you.

Comment: Comparing Eva to Fate/Zero is more like comparing a painting by Giotto to one by Leonardo da Vinci: Leonardo's work is more highly detailed and realistic than Giotto's, but Giotto's work is still interesting, both on its own merits and for its place in the evolution of the style. Also, Eva looks really really good for its time, and the newer releases have been touched up a little.

Comment: @user3289  Look at Kill la Kill, then look at the animation quality of say Patlabor 1 and 2.  Patlabor is more fluid.  Also, Galaxy Express 999 from 1978, or Grave of The Fireflies, or Macross:DYRL.  Heck, how about MS Gundam: Stardust Memory from 1991.  Never mind the animation, lets talk what is actually important:  Story, character and plot development, continuity, etc.  Also....Cutey Honey > KLK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the animation is superior in many cases for 90s shows. So your argument is not valid.

Evangelion should be watched in the order released (Series => EoE => Rebulids) as Rebulids are clearly not remakes.

On the other hand if you don't feel like watching the series why would you do so? Just because it's a classic? Worthless.

Comment: 90s animation is superior to 2005+ animation ?! How is that even possible ?

I want to watch it because I see it being mentioned and recommended everywhere and because I read it's a deconstruction like Madoka. 

I saw some gifs that compare the original show with some newer version so I assumed that they made remake.

Comment: Animation is superior in many cases, yes - back then they weren't such a cheapskates about it. Eva is not show you should watch just because someone recommends it, really.

Comment: "Eva is not show you should watch just because someone recommends it, really." It's not just someone, it's pretty much every anime discussion site and why not ?

Comment: That's entirely different question. And the simplest answer would be: show is not as trivial as most are, at least composition-wise.

Comment: i remember reading that the rebuild is linked to the original series (and to EoE) with evidence suggesting that the red sea is actually LCL and in the first move you see outlines which are the Mass Produced Evas and that Shinji and Asuka "rebuilt" the world and themselves back to an earlier state in hopes to prevent what happened and that the obvious changes like how Adam looks was caused by them not truly understanding everything......ofcause that could just be speculation

Comment: @Memor-X  There is a red sea in the original series as well, and dear lords this non registered user is annoying.  Animation from pre 2005 is superior in many ways.  Also, if OP wants to watch it because it's mentions everywhere why was he complaining about the animation quality.   *rips hair out due to spoiled current gen anime fans*

Comment: Also. as Asuka would say "Anta Baka?!?"

Answer (score 3):

You could watch the evangellion rebuild movies, but some plot points change, some things are left out and the third movie is seemingly (I havent seen it yet) quite different altogether.

Again, I would recommend that you should watch the series first, but you could just watch the films, they don't nessicarily require any knowledge about the series to watch.

Comment: If you are aware of the content of the movies and series just note that [Rebuild is a sequel](http://droptable.pl/public/rebuilds_are_sequel.jpg)

Comment: I guess that asking why the rebuilds have the same scenes from the original series would spoil the show right ?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WMG/NeonGenesisEvangelion That's a theory that hasn't been confirmed, Regardless, he should be able to watch the rebuilds as a standalone

Comment: Plus most of the visuals which are used for the sequel interpretation already has an in-universe, non-sequel-related explanation, the **only** thing that has no in-universe explanation is Kaworu's cryptic dialogue (which is pretty much 90% of everything he says).